# ruby rails cache_key key-based cache expiration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching

I've already read DHH's key-based cache explanation and the caching rails guide, but I still have a question on ActiveRecord results.

If I cache a results page and a record is updated, I know it will result in a cache miss for that record, but what if the individual records are static, but additional results may be returned?
e.g.

```
#returns 100 results
@results = Foo.all
```

... 2 hours later

```
#returns 100 unchanged results + 5 more results for 105
@results = Foo.all
```

cached partial

```
<% cache ['v1', @results] do %>
  <% render :partial => 'bar' %>
<%end%>
```

Will the additional results be shown?   What do I need to do to ensure that cached + latest results get shown?

Comment: Are you using Rails 3.2 with the `cache_digests` gem or Rails 4?

Comment: rails 3.2 with dalli for memcached, cache_digests not installed